# SQL Server 2005 Data Types and VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I would like to know how can I use tinyint in SQL Server 2005 with VB.NET. Please let me know if someone know all data types in SQL Server 2005 are matching to which VB.NET Data types. I face that problem now.

For example: tinyint in VB.NET, money in VB.NET, smalldatetime in VB.NET.

Thanks you all in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx